# mod_rewrite backslash escape

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am currently using mod_rewrite to rewrite some of my URLs but am having a problem when using 2 parameters. My desired result is to have Search/search-term/Page-1 but when I use the following...

```
RewriteRule ^Search/([^/.]+)/Page-([0-9]+)$ Search/index.php?search=$1&pageno=$2 [L]
```

it doesn't work properly. I have since found that the problem is the first / after Search because when I change the rule to...

```
RewriteRule ^Search-([^/.]+)/Page-([0-9]+)$ Search/index.php?search=$1&pageno=$2 [L]
```

then the URL rewrite works perfectly.

Do I need to escape the first backslash somehow? Can anyone think why this would not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you placed this file in `/Search`, perhaps?

Comment: The first rule works fine for me.